# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '`', expecting ')'

Tags: массивы, php

Проблема с массивом php:

```
$array = array("!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "-", "_", "+", "=", ";", ":", ",", ".", "/", "?", "\", "|", "`", "~", "[", "]", "{", "}", "");
```

Вывод:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '`', expecting ')' in /home/b8765/public_html/wetest.php on line 2

Как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте

```
"\`"
```

Comment: точно спасибо, забыл про каретки и спец. символы! Думал не пригодится;)

Answer (score 3):

Проблема тут чуть раньше. нужно заэкранировать \

```
, "\\",
```

Answer (score 2):

`"\\"` или `'\'` вместо `"\"`.

Обратная кавычка тут не при чём.

Comment: За ``'\'`` тоже получите ошибку

Comment: Да, тормознул :)

Answer (score 0):

Пользуй не ", а '.

Дело в том, что при использовании двойной кавычки php в строке ищет переменные и спец.символы.

P.S. Да и с одинарными кавычками работает шустрее. Так что, например, $array["name"] будет более тормознуто, чем $array['name']. Как правило, эта разница незаметна на первый взгляд, но... существенная разница видна на продакшне при большущей нагрузке.